# How do I use nested COUNT formulas to do different SUMS depending on what data is present?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to get cell `A24` to conduct two separate `SUM` functions depending on the data within other cells.

If cell `F6` on sheet `DEPOSIT LOG` ***AND*** cell `J3` on sheet `WITHDRAWAL LOG` both have data within them then I would like the following `SUM` complete : `=SUM('DEPOSIT LOG'!F6)-('WITHDRAWAL LOG'!J3)`

However, if there is only data in `F6` then I want cell `A24` to `=` `F6`

If `F6` and `J3` are both blanks I would like `A24` to also be blank

This is the current formula in cell `A24` :

`=IF(COUNT('DEPOSIT LOG'!F6)=1,SUM('DEPOSIT LOG'!F6)-('WITHDRAWAL LOG'!J3),"")`

If someone could tweak this or suggest an edit I that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula, please:

```
=IF(AND('DEPOSIT LOG'!F6<>"",'WITHDRAWAL LOG'!J3<>""),'DEPOSIT LOG'!F6-'WITHDRAWAL LOG'!J3,IF('DEPOSIT LOG'!F6<>"",'DEPOSIT LOG'!F6,""))
```

Comment: could you possibly take a look at my latest question?

Comment: @Excel newman: Where your question is? Did you place a link and I am missing it?

Comment: If you go on my profile you should be able to see it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66870595/what-formula-will-allow-me-to-complete-certain-sums-depending-on-the-data-of-a-d

Comment: @Excel newman: I am not available now. Very busy at the office... If no answer to your question, I can look at it after some hours when I will be at home.

Comment: thanks that would be really great if you could, no rush though!