# What formula will allow me to complete certain SUMs depending on the data of a different cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2019

[image]This is an example spreadsheet of trading wins and losses within a year.

I am trying to get cell `I6` on sheet `MONTHLY STATS - SPREADS` to populate a `0` if there have been no `L`'s to count between the dates of `1 Mar 21` and `31 Mar 21` on sheet `SPREADS LOG`.

But I only want this `0` to populate if there is data present in cell `H6`. If there is no data in `H6` I would like `I6` to be blank. (note I cannot use a number format to hide these `0`'s in cell `I6` as I am trying to average the complete `I` columnm later on in the sheet)

Whilst it is doing this cell `I6` must also be able to run the `COUNTIFS` & `SUM` formulas shown below.

IMPORTANT NOTE: This must also work the reverse way. e.g. if there are no `W`'s between the dates I want a `0` populated in the `WON` column once data is put into the `LOST` column.

This is the formula I am currently using in cell `I6` :

`=IF(H6="", "",IF(COUNTIFS('SPREADS LOG'!P:P,"L",'SPREADS LOG'!R:R,">="&DATE(2021,3,1),'SPREADS LOG'!R:R,"<="&DATE(2021,3,31)),COUNTIFS('SPREADS LOG'!P:P,"L",'SPREADS LOG'!R:R,">="&DATE(2021,3,1),'SPREADS LOG'!R:R,"<="&DATE(2021,3,31)),"0"))`

If anyone could tweak this or suggest an edit that would be great.

Comment: better to show how your data is structured on the `SPREADS LOG` sheet and clarify further on what exactly "Whilst it is doing this cell I6 must also be able to run the COUNTIFS & SUM formulas shown below." is aiming to achieve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a formula that will do what you're intending.

Cell `H6`:

```
=LET(LOSSES,COUNTIFS('SPREADS LOG'!$P:$P,"L",'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,">="&$A6,'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,"<="&EDATE($A6,1)),WINS,COUNTIFS('SPREADS LOG'!$P:$P,"W",'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,">="&$A6,'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,"<"&EDATE($A6,1)),IF(AND(LOSSES=0,WINS=0),"",WINS))
```

Cell `I6`:

```
=LET(LOSSES,COUNTIFS('SPREADS LOG'!$P:$P,"L",'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,">="&$A6,'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,"<="&EDATE($A6,1)),WINS,COUNTIFS('SPREADS LOG'!$P:$P,"W",'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,">="&$A6,'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,"<"&EDATE($A6,1)),IF(AND(LOSSES=0,WINS=0),"",LOSSES))
```

Using an empty string `""` instead of `0` works perfectly for excluding the cell from `SUM` and `COUNTIFS` formulas without breaking them.

Please note that you cannot use the other cell's value for deciding whether to populate a `0` value or not, since this would create a circular reference.

Versions without `LET`:

Cell `H6`:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS('SPREADS LOG'!$P:$P,"L",'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,">="&$A6,'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,"<"&EDATE($A6,1))=0,COUNTIFS('SPREADS LOG'!$P:$P,"W",'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,">="&$A6,'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,"<"&EDATE($A6,1))=0),"",COUNTIFS('SPREADS LOG'!$P:$P,"W",'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,">="&$A6,'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,"<"&EDATE($A6,1)))
```

Cell `I6`:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS('SPREADS LOG'!$P:$P,"L",'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,">="&$A6,'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,"<"&EDATE($A6,1))=0,COUNTIFS('SPREADS LOG'!$P:$P,"W",'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,">="&$A6,'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,"<"&EDATE($A6,1))=0),"",COUNTIFS('SPREADS LOG'!$P:$P,"L",'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,">="&$A6,'SPREADS LOG'!$R:$R,"<"&EDATE($A6,1)))
```

These formulas assume the dates in your column `A` contain date values (e.g. `01.03.2021` for March) and are formatted with a custom formatting. This allows you to simply copy the formula for the entire column without manually having to change the dates. I would strongly recommend this approach as it has no disadvantages to your current approach, but a potentially tremendous upside when you add it to your repertoire of automation. If you decide to stick to your approach, you will need to change the conditions inside the `COUNTIFS`.

**Edited because I misunderstood the question and provided an incorrect answer.**

Comment: Hi @riskypenguin, thanks very much for your help, I really appreciate it. I have inputted the formulas however it gives the NAME error. I have tried to see why and cannot work it out. I am not too bothered about manually changing dates as most of my sheets are done this way. Column A of the sheet we are working on does not contain any dates, simply text as you can see on screen. Hope this helps?

Comment: The `NAME` error is most likely due to your version of Excel not yet supporting [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) yet. I added a version without `LET`. Please note that there is no visible difference between entering the months as text and entering them as dates and using a custom formatting like `MMMM` (this is applicable for my Excel version, might differ for yours). I would strongly recommend using dates here instead of text.

Comment: Thanks again. Can I ask which version of Excel you are using, I would like to upgrade. Formulas both inputted without errors however I am unsure they are producing the result we are looking for. So far in March, there has been one ```L``` which is recorded in the ```SPREADS LOG``` sheet, and it has not shown in the 'lost' column of the sheet we are working on. If it makes things easier I can email the sheet to you, I understand how hard it can be working only with a screenshot.

Comment: Sure, feel free to send it to riskypenguin_so@protonmail.com and I'll take a look later today.

Comment: Ah, I forgot: I'm using Microsoft Office 365 under an educational license provided by my university.